# "make a request of" or "make a request to"

Tags: prepositions

From [NPR](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=272041622)

***BRIEF INTRODUCTION***: Elisofon is a photographer, he asked to take a picture of a King of the Congo for Life Magazine. Staples is a curator who created an exhibit with Elisofon. And Stamberg is a NPR correspondent.

***QUESTION***: The question is simple. For the phrase ***make a request of*** in the following quote, I feel very strange. Given the fact that the request(bring out of a mirror) is made by the King of Congo, ***to*** the photographer(Elisofon), how about ***make a request to***? That is, ***Once he was ready, the king made a request to Elisofon.*** The word *Of* in the quote makes me feel more like the request is made by the King, not the Elisofon.

***QUOTE***:

> STAPLES: It took him(the King of Congo) three hours to get dressed for the photograph. And the costume, itself, weighs over 300 pounds.
>
> STAMBERG: Once he was ready, the king ***made a request of*** Elisofon.
>
> STAPLES: The king wanted a full-length mirror brought out so he could see how he looked. And Elisofon said: The only other time that happened to me was with Ginger Rogers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepositions are confusing, but this particular use has its logic.

You are thinking of the King speaking **to** the photographer; but this English idiom is driven by the quality of what is said. When you ask for a *favour* or a *gift* or make a *demand* or a *request* you are asking the other person to give you something, and the idiom employs a preposition which expresses not the direction of the communication but the direction of the giving which is to follow, *from* the person requested back to the person making the request.

The preposition might have been *from*, but in English the prepositions *of* and *from* have a great deal of overlap, and had even more overlap in the past. Note, for instance, that titles and identifiers which express a person's place of origin use *of* rather than *from*: the Duke *of* York, Auld Wat *of* Harden, and so forth. Very far back in history we held an election between *of* and *from* in this context, and *of* won.

So in English we do not say *made a request **to***; we say *made a request **of***.